# Need to track Outlook responses after initially setting to "uncheck/ Not" request responses

Tags: microsoft-outlook

I have scheduled a large meeting and initially set it so that I would not receive every response. I figured If they accept it will still show in the tracking as accepted, which does not seem to be the case. If I updated the meeting to request responses will it require everyone to accept again if they already had and then show tracking?

Answer (score 0):

Based on my experience and tests, I think so.

Actually, if the meeting is set to "not request response", your attendee wouldn't send any respose, so there wouldn't be any response information in your meeting and we couldn't track it in Outlook. And the tracking may just begin when you update the meeting to "request response", so it couldn't display any response unless your attendee accept/decline it again and send the response for you.